# advanced filter excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to do a filter in a excel sheet, I would like to  know if is possible do a filter like this

```
 List<string> listFilter = new List<string>();
            listFilter.Add("3");
            listFilter.Add("4");

            object _missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng1 = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "A1048576"];
            oRng1.AutoFilter(1, listFilter, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, _missing, true);
            oRng1.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

I know that this code doesn't work but I would like to do a dinamic list in the filter parameter.
Could someone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about passing lists, but you can definitely pass arrays:

```
string[] listfilter = new string[] { "2", "3", "4" };
xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B50").AutoFilter(1, listfilter, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues,
    Missing.Value, true);
```

You can find the different members of the `XlAutoFilterOperator` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlautofilteroperator.aspx).

It might also be an idea to try to find the last-used row in the sheet rather than setting the filter for the entire column as that might slow things down a little:

```
int lastRow = xlWorksheet.Range["A:A"].Find("*", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, Missing.Value,
    Missing.Value).Row;
```

Comment: What if I want to filter the column based on `>=` criteria? So i want something like the column values should be greater than or equal to one of the values in `listfilter` array. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Hi @Raj. Sorry, I haven't touched this code in eight years! I have no idea how you'd do that now. My suggestion would be to create a question of your own and you'll get a lot more attention on it from others.

Comment: Cool! Thanks anyway Sid