# add filter to excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a c# app that runs some code and produces a report in Excel. The report is fine - do all the formatting except for when I go to put the autofilter on.

I get the error message "AutoFilter method of Range class failed". When I step through the code I can add a filter via VBA and it works - not sure why its not working from within my c# app.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Range rngFilter = _xlWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "L2");
rngFilter.AutoFilter();
rngFilter = null;
```

Comment: vba script and C# are 2 different things and vba script does not always guarantee that it would work in VB.Net as well can you share the error message that you are getting..?

Comment: yes I understand vba & c# are different was just a quick dirty test. The error message is "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

Comment: have you checked the msdn documentation on this [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter%28VS.80%29.aspx) also your're not passing anything to the `AutoFilter()` method

Comment: yes I have checked that but have to be honest didn't find it very helpful

Comment: here is a similar question perhaps you can use this as a guide to expose some hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317241/advanced-filter-excel-with-c-sharp

Comment: turns out despite the msdn documentation the parameters are not optional! Using the missing.value the code now works

Comment: glad that I could point you to something that helped you quickly fix your issue..